# Replace the "^" in the string in java

Tags: java, string

I Replace the other characters in the string using

```
String slash_data=cap_data.replaceAll("/", "%2F");
```

But during the Replacement of "^" It doesn't replaced in that position.

```
String string_data="058000657^HELLO HI  /"
String cap_data=string_data.replaceAll("^", "%5E");
```

What is wrong in this?

Comment: Escape it, `replaceAll` takes a regex...

Comment: `String capData = stringData.replace("^", "%5E");`...

Comment: @Reimeus I did, I am an idiot :D sorry

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `replaceAll` method takes a regular expression, rather than a literal string, and `^` is a regular expression symbol meaning "beginning of the current line". So it's not really looking for a `^` character at all.

You need to escape the `^` character: try `\\^` instead.

(This is also somewhat confusing. A single backslash in a string acts as an escape character, so you need your string to consist of a single backslash followed by a `^`. But the way you write a single backslash in your source code is as `\\`, because you need to escape the backslash...)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.. now I got it.

Answer (score 3):

^ is a Special character in regex. It means the beginning of a string. So you have to escape it:

```
String cap_data=string_data.replaceAll("\\^", "%5E");
```